# Wordpress 3.3.1 not cropping featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

When I add a featured image to any post the image is not cropped but it is always displayed full size.

The media settings are ok...

even when I call `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` in my theme, the full image is shown instead of the thumbnail.

What I am doing wrong? It is probably my 30th Wordpress based site and I never had this problem before.

Thanks

Comment: This works only for images that were uploaded _after_ the thumbnail was registered. Is that the case?

Comment: yes, this is the case. I guess there is a plugin interfering.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `the_post_thumbnail()` $size parameter is 'post-thumbnail'. You can set that by adding this line to your functions.php :

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(125,125,true);
```

If this still doesn't update your image's size, you may need to use a plugin like ["Regenerate Thumbnails."](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Alternately, you can set the image to use one of the Media Options-defined sized by passing a $size parameter to your thumbnail template tag like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); // display post thumbnail with the "Thumbnail" size defined in Settings > Media.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in functions.php?

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Yes, I am using the Twenty Ten theme as base theme

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when you crop an image in the Wordpress image editor and save it, the featured image is still the uncropped one? That's a bug in Wordpress, please see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19889. The editor does not create thumbnails for custom sizes (including 'post-thumbnail'), only the ones defined in options ('thumbnail', 'medium' and 'large').